# Ruby on Rails - Why can't I use ActiveRecord::Base methods? Where to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, each, collect

I've been trying to use ActiveRecord::Base methods such as .each and .collect in my application but I keep getting undefined method errors! Perhaps I have a shaky knowledge of Ruby. It seems like I can't use these methods in my controller, methods or views?

For example, the code below will give me an undefined method 'collect':

```
@articles = Article.collect{|x| x.publisher == 'Bloomberg'}
```

Another example will also give an error:

```
array = []
@articles = Article.each do |x|
   if x.publisher == 'Bloomberg'
      array << x
   end
end
```

I can't user these methods in my controller, my model or views. Where can I use them? Can anyone tell me if my fundamental Ruby/Rails code is wrong?

I'm using Rails 4.20 and Ruby 2.1.5p273

Comment: I think (would need to check) that you need to use `Article.all.each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.each` and `.collect` are collection methods defined in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) mixin in Ruby, not methods defined in `ActiveRecord::Base`.

In order to call `.each` or `.collect` you need a collection object that responds to these method calls.  So use:

```
@articles = Article.all.collect{|x| x.publisher == 'Bloomberg'}
```

and,

```
array = []
@articles = Article.all.each do |x|
   if x.publisher == 'Bloomberg'
      array << x
   end
end
```

To comment on where you can use them, you would use them either in model or controller, but not in view.  I would recommend placing this code in a class method or even a scope in your Article model.  Example:

```
# app/models/article.rb

# Class method example:
# Usage: Article.by_publisher('Bloomberg')
def self.by_publisher(publisher_name)
  where(publisher: publisher_name)
end

# Scope example
# Usage: Article.by_publisher('Bloomberg')
scope :by_publisher, ->(publisher_name) { where(publisher: publisher_name) }
```

Then in your controller or view you'd use `each` or `collect` similar to the following block:

```
Article.by_publisher('Bloomberg').each do |article|
  # article.title
end
```

Comment: Wow! That helps a lot. I'm sure other noobies will have the same problems so on behalf of us all, thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: hmm... it seems like .all is also not allowed. it generates the same error?

Answer (score 1):

Methods collect and each are defined on [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html). You will need to get a collection of articles first in order to use them. Just calling Article will get you Article model class, you need to use Article.all instead.

```
@articles = Article.all.collect{|x| x.publisher == 'Bloomberg'}
```

However you probably want to do this on database level. It's not a good idea to load all articles in memory and the filter them out, your database can do this for you much faster. Try out following code.

```
@articles = Article.where(publisher: 'Bloomberg')
```

Comment: Noted! Thanks for the tip, I definitely have a few places where .where would be useful :)

Comment: Right on on the Enumerable mixin!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using scopes. Here is a good place to start: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

If you don't want to do that, then you can do the following in your controller:

```
@articles = Article.where(publisher: 'Bloomberg')
```

Comment: Awesome! I wish I could give all of you checkmarks, thanks for your help! :)